# ProperCase in VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net

I want that as user type a sentence, Program should automatically correct it to ProperCase or Sentence Case. To achive this, I used vbStrConv.ProperCase in TextChanged Event of particular Text box. But problem is It doesn't allow to input upper Characters anywhere except starting of the word.

It should not change the case of Manually typed UPPER Characters, I mean how can I make user able to enter UPPER CASE Characters also ?

C# code is also accepted.

Comment: I'll pass up the opportunity to recommend code that changes my name into lowercase :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `TextInfo` for this purpose

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase("abc");
```

Comment: So not a long winded command, then, really?...

Comment: @paul you can drop the namespaces if you've imported it

Comment: Oh, I know - just such a useful command buried so far down a namespace...

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do it with code as you want behaviour not available through the framework methods. Something like

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub TextBoxUppercaseFirstLetters(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim tb = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
        Dim s = tb.Text
        Dim cursorPos = tb.SelectionStart

        Dim wb = (" ,;:.'""" & vbCrLf).ToCharArray()

        Dim t = ""
        For i = 0 To s.Length - 1
            If i = 0 Then
                t = CStr(s(i)).ToUpper()
            Else
                If wb.Contains(s(i - 1)) Then
                    t &= CStr(s(i)).ToUpper()
                Else
                    t &= s(i)
                End If
            End If
        Next

        tb.Text = t
        tb.SelectionStart = cursorPos

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        AddHandler TextBox1.TextChanged, AddressOf TextBoxUppercaseFirstLetters

    End Sub
End Class
```

This will also give you the opportunity to not uppercase letters where that should not be done, e.g. [Gerard ’t Hooft](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~hooft101/ap.html).